# JavaFX: Platform.runLater(task) not recognized for task = new FutureTask<>(new Runnable() {....}?

Tags: multithreading, javafx-8, sleep, runnable, futuretask

Over the last two weeks I have studied 10 different ways to avoid problems with `sleep()`.  The concept of running a block of code on the UI Thread that cannot be interrupted seems the most practical.  So I have proceeded to create a `FutureTask<Void>` object that contains the code not to be interrupted before completed.  The code in `for` loops, `pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color)` sets the new colors for `Circle` Objects in a `Grid Array` that's 32x64.  This has always failed to display the colors when just `sleep(5000)` is invoked between the pixel art files, `FileChooser` selects and assigns to `List<File> selectedFiles`.  Unfortunately the following code will not compile because `runLater` in the `linePlatform.runLater(diplayFileTask);` can't be resolved in the following code:

```
public class PlayPlaylist{

public static List<File> selectedFiles;

public static void play() throws ExecutionException {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:\\ProgramData\\L1 Art Files\\"));
    fileChooser.setTitle("Play One or More Pixel Art Files");
    List<File> selectedFiles = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);
    for (File selectedFile : selectedFiles) {
        try {
            displayFile(selectedFile.getPath());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void displayFile( String pathName) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    FutureTask<Void> displayFileTask = new FutureTask<>(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            path = Paths.get(pathName);
            try {
                pixelByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            int cnt = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                    //int i = r * col + c;
                    //System.out.println("\nr = " + r + "  c = " + c);

                    String hexRGB = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X",
                            pixelByteArray[cnt++],                  //red
                            pixelByteArray[cnt++],                  //green
                            pixelByteArray[cnt++]);                 //blue

                    Color color = Color.valueOf(hexRGB);
                    //System.out.println("\ncolor is " + color);

                    pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color);
                }
            }
            String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
            window.setTitle(MessageFormat.format("Pixel Array {0} x {1}    File:  {2}", Integer.toString(row), Integer.toString(col), fileName));
        }
    }, null); // displayFile
    Platform.runLater(displayFileTask);
    displayFileTask.get();
    sleep(5000);
}
```

I've followed the example(s) closely in Stack Overflow and fail to see the problem(s).

I have more details on past attempts posted on Stack Overflow at: [Wait() & Sleep() Not Working As Thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003813/wait-sleep-not-working-as-thought?noredirect=1#comment55764295_34003813).

I also have the two UI windows posted on the web at: [Virtual Art](https://virtualartsite.wordpress.com/).  I think the pixel art shown in the Pixel Array window clarifies the goal of creating a user-defined slide show.

Can anyone correct my errors?  Do you think my `sleep(5000)` is in the best location?

**Answering James_D's questions.**  This is my best solution to your answer at my first post, [Wait() & Sleep() Not Working As Thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003813/wait-sleep-not-working-as-thought?noredirect=1#comment55764295_34003813).  I was actually following your logic and code posted at, [java thread immediately update UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569709/java-thread-immediately-update-ui).

I save and display pixel art files that are 32x64.  You can see an example posted on the [Virtual Art](https://virtualartsite.wordpress.com/) website.  I thought it would be straight forward to create a slide show under `Playlist`, click `Play`.  I would use the same class and `OpenFile(pathname)` method in a for loop to display each file selected and placed in the `ArrayList<>` but pause by putting `Thread.sleep(5000)` in the loop.

As you pointed out, this doesn't work, as I best understand, because the `Thread.sleep(5000)` interrupts the UI Thread causing a "skip" over of just the display code of all the files looped through.  But last pixel art file  **will appear** after 5 secs.

I thought your answer in the post referenced above applied: You create a block of code using `FutureTask<Void>` and `Platform.runLater<task>` that can't be interrupted until completed. I thought the `FutureTask<Void>` runs on the UI Thread and would finish displaying the pixel art file before `Thread.sleep(5000)` could interrupt.

At 68 and retired, I'm new to JavaFX and trying to develop this RGB LED product that can be programmed with a basic pixel editor.  Learning JavaFX is a real challenge for me, **thanks for your time and patience**.

Comment: _concept of running a block of code on the UI Thread that cannot be interrupted seems the most practical_ no, no, no, on the contrary: you _must not_ ever think of anything in the UI as uninteruptable! The result would be a sluggish/unresponsive UI that would annoy your users. That's why you do all the time-consuming processing plus sleeping in the background. BTW: for highest probability to get concrete help it's best to provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the exact problem.

Comment: Can you explain what the overall aim is here? (Is it a slideshow? Why not use a `Timeline`, or at least a `ScheduledService`?) I don't actually understand what you are trying to do with the threading: I assume `play()` is called as the result of a user event, so it is on the FX Application Thread, and consequently so is `displayFile`. But then why are you using `Platform.runLater(...)` if you are already on the FX Application Thread? And this also means your `Thread.sleep(...)` is on the FX Application Thread, which you must not do.  Or have I misinterpreted the context?

Comment: FWIW I pasted the code into a context in which it would work (i.e. defined a bunch of `static` variables of the appropriate type), and the `Platform.runLater(...)` compiled just fine. I assume `sleep(5000);` is `Thread.sleep(5000);`. But executing `Platform.runLater(displayFileTask);` and then `displayFileTask.get();` from the FX Application Thread would surely result in deadlock.

Comment: James_D:  Thanks for your help.  I will answer your Q's  above where I have more room to be clearer.

Comment: @kleopatra:  What does SSCCE stand for?

Comment: @James_D   Yes, I'm using Thread.sleep(5000).  What does FWIW I stand for?  I posted detailed answers to your under Edit; I hope there clear enough.  Thanks again.

Comment: "FWIW" = "For what it's worth"

Comment: @sgroen Usually a "cannot be resolved" error has to do with library imports.  Have you correctly imported to class?  Can you create a simple example that I could run if I had the javafx dependency?

Comment: [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example: SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and the StackOverflow equivalent: [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jewelsea:  I have a new post using pseudo code which should clarify the question and solution.  I have admired your many well constructed answers and would really appreciate your answer as I'm desperate. (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190772/how-avoid-thread-sleep-in-a-for-loop-from-interrupting-the-ui-thread) How to avoid Thread.sleep() in a for loop from interrupting the UI Thread