# How to avoid Thread.sleep() in a for loop from interrupting the UI Thread?

Tags: javafx-8, thread-sleep

I have the following pseudo code to clarify my problem and a solution.  My original posting and detailed results are on Stack Overflow at: [Wait() & Sleep() Not Working As Thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003813/wait-sleep-not-working-as-thought?noredirect=1#comment55764295_34003813).

```
public class PixelArtSlideShow {  // called with click of Menu item.

   create List<File>  of each selected pixelArtFile
   for (File pixelArtFile : List<File>) {
      call displayFiles(pixelArtFile);
      TimeUnits.SECONDS.sleep(5); }
   }

    public static void displayFiles(File pixelArtFile) {

       for (loop array rows)
          for (loop array columns)
             read-in sRGB for each pixel - Circle Object
             window.setTitle(....)
}

// when above code is used to Open a pixelArtFile, it will appear instantly in  a 32 x 64 array
```

PROBLEM:  As detailed extensively on the other post.  Each `pixelArtFile` will display the `setTitle()` correctly and pause for about 5 secs but the Circle’s will not change to the assigned color except for the last file, after the 5 secs have passed.  It's like all the code in the TimeUnits.SECONDS.sleep(5);  are skipped EXCEPT the `window.setTitle(...)`?

My understanding is the `TimeUnits.SECONDS.sleep(5);` interrupts the UI Thread uncontrollable and I guess must somehow be isolated to allow the `displayFiles(File pixelArtFile)` to fully execute.

Could you please show me the most straight forward way to solve this problem using the pseudo code for a more completed solution?

I have tried `Runnables`, `Platform.runLater()`, `FutureTask<Void>`, etc. and I'm pretty confused as to how they are meant to work and exactly coded.

I also have the two UI windows posted on the web at: [Virtual Art](https://virtualartsite.wordpress.com/). I think the `pixelArtFile` shown in the Pixel Array window may clarify the problem.

THANKS

Comment: Pseudocode or code snippets are rarely the right thing to use in a StackOverflow questions such as this one. What is usually most helpful for you and prospective answers is to include: a) [complete, compilable, standalone, *minimal* code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that somebody can copy and paste to reproduce the issue (and only the issue) at hand, b) a description in english of your objective, c) a description in english of the problem that you are encountering.

Comment: Is it best to post the MCVE on GitHub?

Comment: No it is best to include the mcve in the question.  MCVE's are always small enough that they can fit inside a question without any additional external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sleep the UI thread.  A Timeline will probably do what you want.

```
List<File> files;
int curFileIdx = 0;

// prereq, files have been appropriately populated.
public void runAnimation() {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), event -> {
                if (!files.isEmpty()) {
                    displayFile(curFileIdx);
                    curFileIdx = (curFileIdx + 1) % files.size();
                }
            })
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}

// prereq, files have been appropriately populated.
public void displayFile(int idx) {
    File fileToDisplay = files.get(idx);
    // do your display logic.
}
```

Note, in addition to the above, you probably want to run a separate [task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to read the file data into memory, and just have a `List<ModelData>` where `ModelData` is some class for data you have read from a file.  That way you wouldn't be continuously running IO in your animation loop.  For a five second per frame animation, it probably doesn't matter much.  But, for a more frequent animation, such optimizations are very important.

Comment: Thanks to jewelsea for this detailed solution which solved my problems.  Without the level detail presented I would still have been struggling.